# Unable to find phonon library

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, libraries

I am trying to build an application that requires the phonon library...

I got an error because the lphonon was not found. so I tried to look for it... there is no "phonon" on my system.

I tried installing it

> sudo apt-get install libqt4-phonon
>   sudo apt-get install libqt4-phonon-dev

neither worked, so I tried

> sudo apt-get install phonon

It worked... and i was able to find it in

> \usr\lib\i386-linux-gnu

, but the files i find are

> libphonon.so.4 and libphonon.so.4.6.0

I added this path in the project file

> unix:INCLUDEPATH += /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu

this was there before

> unix:QT += phonon

Do I have to change the name of the lib ? How can I make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that finally worked was to install the deb package myself...

https://packages.debian.org/sid/libphonon-dev

Answer (score 0):

On my system there isn't this package, but thee is something available called libphonon4qt5. I suggest you go into synaptic, search for phonon and pick the package you need.

Comment: Thank you i was just updating my question... I was able to download... something but I don't know if it is right... I must use qt4.